# Class variable in python context class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a series of nested contexts, and need to keep trace of their relative relationship.  But I ran in the following behavior that I did not expect:

```
class NestedContext():
    _current = None
    def __enter__(self):
        self.parent = self._current
        self._current = self

    def __exit__(self, _type, _value, _tb):
         self._current = self.parent

with NestedContext():
    assert NestedContext._current is not None # fails
    with NestedContext():
        pass
```

The assert fail because the class variable `_current` is None, which is unexpected, since I thought `__enter__` just set it to self.  This seems to be related some deeper behavior of Python context that I don't understand.  Can anyone explain?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are testing the **class attribute**. You set `self._current`, an **instance attribute**.

If you wanted to set the class attribute, you need to qualify it as such:

```
class NestedContext(object):
    _current = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.parent = self._current
        NestedContext._current = self

    def __exit__(self, _type, _value, _tb):
         NestedContext._current = self.parent
```

When *reading* an attribute, Python searches through the layers of instance, class, and base classes. But when *setting* an attribute, no such layering takes place. So `self._current` will fall back to `NestedContext` if there is no such attribute on `self`, but `self._current = some_value` sets that attribute on `self`, not on the class.

I also used `object` as the parent class for `NestedContext`; unless there are compelling reasons not to (e.g. you are working with legacy code that relies on the old behaviours), you always want to get [new style classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

Demo (with addition of a `_name` attribute and a `__repr__` method):

```
>>> class NestedContext(object):
...     _current = None
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self._name = name
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '<NestedContext({._name!r})>'.format(self)
...     def __enter__(self):
...         self.parent = self._current
...         NestedContext._current = self
...     def __exit__(self, _type, _value, _tb):
...          NestedContext._current = self.parent
... 
>>> with NestedContext('outer'):
...     print NestedContext._current
...     with NestedContext('inner'):
...         print NestedContext._current
...         print NestedContext._current.parent
... 
<NestedContext('outer')>
<NestedContext('inner')>
<NestedContext('outer')>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I do have the `object` superclass in my code, but in my hurry to create a mock example to stackoverflow, I forgot it.
I did not realize that Python does not resolve to class variable in setter.  I suppose the best thing to do for setting class variable is write a setter `@classmethod`. Is this correct?

Comment: @vimsical: you could use a classmethod, but be aware that if you are subclassing, then class methods are bound to the class of the current instance, not a specific class in the inheritance tree. You could also use `type(self)._current = self` to get the same effect.

Comment: Thank you again! I like your last suggestion. It leaves no ambiguity what that line of code does.